# Confluent kafka go client memory leak

Tags: go, apache-kafka, memory-leaks

My service consumes messages from one kafka topic. While the consumer is idle and blocked waiting for messages I see a continuous and linear increase in the POD memory. GO pprof proves that the go memory consumption is constant around 40 MB, at the same time POD metrics show more than 100 MB is consumed.

This leads me to the conclusion that memory is consumed in the C library librdkafka as mentioned here https://zendesk.engineering/hunting-down-a-c-memory-leak-in-a-go-program-2d08b24b617d

The solution to the memory consumption in librdkafka in the link above was to consume the OffsetCommitResponse events that librdkafka produces. Here is the quote from the link:

> It turned out that librdkafka was generating an event every time it
> received an OffsetCommitResponse from the Kafka broker (which, with
> our auto-commit interval set to 5 seconds, was pretty often), and
> placing it in a queue for our app to handle. However, our application
> was not actually handling events from that queue, so the size of that
> queue grew without bound

Does anyone know how to consume these events in go? unfortunately the link above didn't mention the solution

Comment: Forgot to mention that I use https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go v1.9.1

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by counting the number of consumed messages in my service. When the number of consumed messages reaches a configured value e.g. 100,000 in my case, then I simply close and recreate the kafka consumer and producer.

This solution is neither elegant nor doesn't solve the original issue, but hey it stabilized my production. Now I have a flat memory consumption curve.